# Is there any other way to display list in a lightning component other than lightning:datatable?

Tags: lightning-datatable

I have a list of objects to be displayed on an `<aura:component>`. And I know, I can use datatable to display it. But, my client asked me to use a [html card](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cards.asp) instead of a datatable to make it look more stylish. So, is it possible to do that? Is it possible to display cards inside a loop in an `<aura:component>`? Or is there any other way to display lists without using datatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have anything in iteration using [aura iteration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:iteration),

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.SObjectList}" var="item">
       {!item.Id}
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: thanks very much,